# Use of the word educated

Tags: word-usage

One person said that Electronic Arts Sports are based in the USA. A second person responded that they are located in Canada, and said "Get educated".

In my opinion 'educated' can only be used on broad topics which require some sort of learning/studying. Where EA is based is only a fact and not something you can 'get educated on'. Am I wrong? (English not my native language)

Comment: This is supposed to be a humorous retort, not an actual suggestion that the person attend a school at which they will spend years learning where EA is located.

Comment: Supposed to be an insult, but thats not the point. I am asking if "get educated" can be used in such way

Comment: Of course it can. Have you ever heard the phrase "get f***ed" or "get wrecked"? The speaker is not wishing that the person literally be raped or the victim of a car crash. They are expressing contempt in a humorously aggressive manner, usually resulting in both people laughing about it and moving on as opposed to beating the tar out of each other. Ditto for your example. It's just modern slang.

Comment: Think of it as a slang fixed expression, like "Don't be so daft/stupid!"

Comment: "Get some education" would have been better. "some" makes all the difference.

Comment: From one sense of [*educate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/educate):  "**2 b** : to provide with information : INFORM, // *educating* themselves about changes in the industry." So, *get educated* → *become informed*.